# Why does JavaScript Date(milliseconds) give different timezone depending on value of argument?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

Please forgive my ignorance, but could someone perhaps explain to me why JavaScript's `Date(milliseconds)` returns a different timezone when `milliseconds` is smaller than, say, 1e10?

Here's a minimal example of what I am seeing:

JavaScript

```
console.log( new Date( 1e3 ).toString() );
console.log( new Date( 1e10 ).toString() );
console.log( new Date().toString() );
```

Console Output

```
Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:01 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
Sun Apr 26 1970 19:46:40 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Standard Time)
Wed Jul 13 2016 09:06:50 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

Note that the first output has a different timezone (GMT+0100) from the last two (GMT+0200)...

There's probably a good explanation for this, but I don't see it.

Thank you for your help.

Kind regards,
Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing here is not a time-zone change, but Daylight Saving Time (DST) applied to a given time-zone.

Quoting MDN's documentation of [Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset):

*The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and local time. (...)
**Daylight saving time prevents this value from being a constant even for a given locale.***

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I guess using Date's UTC methods would take care of this issue for my application.

Comment: @Dennis Yes, exactly. DST is never applied to UTC.